# WYSIWYG Editor that support editing margin, padding and border

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am searching for long for an editor that let the user to change style attribute like `border`, `padding`, and `margin`

I tested lot of editors, and didn't find. Do you know about editor, that support it?

Editor I tested, and didn't have those buttons (maybe there are but I didn't see)

- ckEditor
- quill
- pen
- medium.js
- textAngular
- and some others...

Comment: ckEditor has the ability to set does values for Tables and Images, etc.. What do you want to set does value on?

Comment: try tinyMCE. I googled ways to set padding and margin and there were a number of results.

Comment: Yeah tinyMCe is a good tool to create html. I used it to manage email templates.

Comment: On DIV, SPAN, BUTTON, and P

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Voog/wysihtml has functionality for changing style attributes on block and inline(or inline block) elements separately.

Look at tests for examples:
Adding styles with formatInline command (applies on selected text when present) https://github.com/Voog/wysihtml/blob/master/test/commands/formatInline_test.js#L127

formatBlock has similar syntax but is meant to insert/change block level elements. (applies on closest block level element when present)

Unfortunately it does not have a functionality to change the style automatically picking inline or block method. The problem is that it is very difficult to know what elements user intended to pick with a selection.

Also currently editor does not guarantee minimal tag wrapping when using styles. Additional `<span>`s or `<div>`s might be created depending on selection.